# Playframework 2.5 Slick + DI

Tags: mysql, scala, playframework, slick

I'm using playframework 2.5 with play slick

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  cache,
  ws,
  "org.scalatestplus.play" %% "scalatestplus-play" % "1.5.0-RC1" % Test,
  "com.madgag.spongycastle" % "core" % "1.53.0.0",
  "org.flywaydb" %% "flyway-play" % "3.0.0",
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick" % "2.0.0",
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick-evolutions" % "2.0.0"
)

resolvers += "scalaz-bintray" at "http://dl.bintray.com/scalaz/releases"


fork in run := false
```

And trying to implement basic CRUD class with DI which is recommended by play official.

```
trait FooService {
  def findById(id: Long)

  final class FooTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[FooModel](tag,"foo"){
    def id = column[Long]("id")
    //....
  }
}

@Singleton
class FooServiceImpl @Inject()(protected val dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider) extends FooService with HasDatabaseConfigProvider[JdbcProfile] {
  import dbConfig.driver.api._

  private lazy val bars = TableQuery[FooTable]

  def findById(id: Long) = db.run(bars.filter{ x => x.id === id}.result)
  //....
}
```

Module.scala

```
override def configure() = {
  //....
  bind(classOf[FooService]).to(classOf[FooServiceImpl])
  //....
}
```

application.conf

```
slick.dbs.default.driver = "slick.driver.MySQLDriver$"
slick.dbs.default.db.driver = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
slick.dbs.default.db.url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/foo"
slick.dbs.default.db.user = "root"
slick.dbs.default.db.password = "password"
```

I get an error `Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: driverClassName specified class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver' could not be loaded` with codes/setting above

the error gets disappear if I add `slick.dbs.default.db.dataSourceClass = "slick.jdbc.DatabaseUrlDataSource"` to application.conf though, I get DB Timeout exception instead.

Since my other play2.4 project(non DI) could connect to a server with same config setting and also I could connect to the server in console, I'm crystal sure that the Db config is correct.

I don't know what causes the issue. Where am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post your build.sbt file too, please.

Comment: @marcospereira updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the mysql driver dependency:

```
libraryDependencies += "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.38"
```

Of course, check the if this version (the latest) is ok or if you need another one.

Comment: ofc, It needs to be there. thanks for answering stupid question.